# Unable to redirect on an url on post logout azure AD

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, logout

I'm trying to send my user on https://localhost:8443/ after they logout from Azure AD.
But they stay stuck on Microsoft.
When they logout they first go to :
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/"apptenant"/oauth2/v2.0/logout?client-request-id=16d3217c-a5cf-434d-90ee-9723365ddbfa&post_logout_redirect_uri=**https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443*](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%22apptenant%22/oauth2/v2.0/logout?client-request-id=16d3217c-a5cf-434d-90ee-9723365ddbfa&post_logout_redirect_uri=**https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8443*)*

with the correct post logout redirection.
They click on their account and then they are send to :
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/"apptenant"/oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%22apptenant%22/oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession)

without any post logout redirection.

in the request logoutsession I have this 2 parameters :
**postLogoutRedirectUriValid: 0** and post_logout_redirect_uri: https://localhost:8443

I don't why I get postLogoutRedirectUriValid = 0 ...

The post logout redirect uri is write in azure AD app registration postlogout and in the authentication object as postLogoutRedirectUri in my angular.

Any ideas !

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip I will look at it.
But something new append :
I try it with an account created on my azure AD and it works...
Before I was trying with my personal Microsoft account, and I get the pb.

So maybe I did not understand perfectly, how it works :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of my idea，your process looks perfect, so I think there should still be a code mismatch. I set up an asp.net project, and when I delete this line `<add key="PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:4436/" />`in web.config, there's a problem with the page not jumping after it's logout.